# How to create an array that sums the value of a 2d array

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
[[2, 3, 4, 6, 9],
 [4, 6, 8, 12, 18],
 [6, 9, 12, 18, 27],
 [8, 12, 16, 24, 36],
 [10, 15, 20, 30, 45],
 [12, 18, 24, 36, 54],
 [14, 21, 28, 42, 63],
 [16, 24, 32, 48, 72],
 [18, 27, 36, 54, 81],
 [20, 30, 40, 60, 90]]
```

I wanted to sum to value into an array.

Basically, I have this array data, how do I get this output.

The output is something like this

```
[2+3+4+6+9, 2+3+4+6+18, 2+3+4+6+27, 2+3+4+6+36, 2+3+4+6+45, 2+3+4+6+54, 2+3+4+6+63, 2+3+4+6+71, 2+3+4+6+81, 2+3+4+6+90, 4+3+4+6+9, ...]
```

I tried something like this and it didn't work

```
final = [] trans = [*zip(*data)]

k = 0 l = 0

while(k != len(trans) * len(data)):   val = 0   m = 0   for d1 in trans:
    val = val + d1[m * l]
    m = m + 1   l = l + 1   k = k + 1   final.append(val)
```

Comment: How did it not work? Be very specific. Also, format code as code, not as quote

Comment: `[sum(sub) for sub in data]`?

Comment: `map(sum,array)`

Comment: @jpp. This is not a dupe if you look at the desired output. OP is not looking for a simple row sum. All the answers just happen to be wrong and OP's wording is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @DanielMana. Could you clarify your question a bit? Provide a more general formula perhaps?

Comment: @Austin. Thanks for persisting. The question is reopened.

Comment: I'm  not sure I understand why the last element shown in the example isn't `2+3+4+12+9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
my_list = [[2, 3, 4, 6, 9],
 [4, 6, 8, 12, 18],
 [6, 9, 12, 18, 27],
 [8, 12, 16, 24, 36],
 [10, 15, 20, 30, 45],
 [12, 18, 24, 36, 54],
 [14, 21, 28, 42, 63],
 [16, 24, 32, 48, 72],
 [18, 27, 36, 54, 81],
 [20, 30, 40, 60, 90]]

sum_list = [sum(i) for i in my_list]
print(sum_list)
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants; doesn't match with expected output, or is it only me who sees different. See `[2+3+4+6+9, 2+3+4+6+18, 2+3+4+6+27, ...]`

Comment: I think he expects the sum, because if he wanted like yours then he would write like this, `[[2+3+4+6+9],......]` or `[(2+3+4+6+9),....]. You cannot make a list of `int` like `[2+3+4+6+9,....]`, where all the values are `int`.

Answer (score 0):

In python2:

```
summed_array = map(sum,array)
```

for python3:

```
summed_array = list(map(sum,array))
```

To do what you have literally requested:

```
[sum(row[:-1]) + x[-1] for row in array for x in array]
```

Comment: This won't produce a list in Python 3

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants; doesn't match with expected output, or is it only me who sees different. See `[2+3+4+6+9, 2+3+4+6+18, 2+3+4+6+27, ...]`

Comment: @Austin. I finally understood what you mean. You're absolutely right. Sorry for all the other stuff I said.